# Is timeIntervalBetween1970AndReferenceDate + timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate = timeIntervalSince1970

Tags: swift, date

I was going through a code and stumbled upon usage of `timeIntervalBetween1970AndReferenceDate` and `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`.

Code is returning a timestamp in milliseconds:

```
return (Date.timeIntervalBetween1970AndReferenceDate + date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate) * 1000
```

Isn't this equivalent to:

```
return date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, there is no difference. `Date` has the type property

```
public static let timeIntervalBetween1970AndReferenceDate: TimeInterval
// The number of seconds from 1 January 1970 to the reference date, 1 January 2001
```

and the instance properties

```
public var timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: TimeInterval { get }
// The interval between the date value and 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001.

public var timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval { get }
// The interval between the date value and 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.
```

which means that for any value `date` of type `Date` the identity

```
Date.timeIntervalBetween1970AndReferenceDate + date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
     == date.timeIntervalSince1970
```

holds. In fact, as we can see in  [Date.swift#L111](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/Date.swift#L111), `timeIntervalSince1970` is implemented as

```
public var timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval {
    return self.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate + Date.timeIntervalBetween1970AndReferenceDate
}
```